Update many on non-pk fields using JDBC Sink Connector
I've a table which is like
Table Name: users
user_id (varchar(16))
company_id (uuid)
state (varchar(36))
city (varchar(36))

pk: user_id, company_id

Query I need to execute using JDBC Sink Connector is
Update users set state = :state1, city = :city1 where user_id = :user_id;
To be updated rows can be >1

Please share what exactly have you been trying so we don't repeat something
